# High voltage on downstream O2 sensor after driving, but low voltage on idle

Tags: o2-sensor, emissions, catalytic-converter, voltage, rich

After driving on the highway, my downstream O2 sensor voltage was a steady 0.8V, which is high.

On the other hand, when idling before the drive, it was a steady 0.3V.

Is it normal for the downstream O2 sensor voltage to be so high after driving? Does this mean I have a bad catalytic converter, or is there another explanation?

Comment: How did you get on with the articles? See https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/82358/10976

Comment: @SolarMike Also, I read a few articles before asking, and they say that a high downstream (post-cat) O2 sensor voltage could mean that my catalytic converter is not working well. I’m just asking to get some second opinions